# "Will not add file alias 'samefile' ('SameFile' already exists in index)" when `git add` operation

Tags: git

I download linux' kernel source, and want to `git add` them all.

When I `git add .`, git starts add them. But soon it returns an error:

```
fatal: Will not add file alias 'include/linux/netfilter/xt_connmark.h' ('include/linux/netfilter/xt_CONNMARK.h' already exists in index)
```

That's weird, `xt_connmark.h` and `xt_CONNMARK.h` are **TOTALLY DIFFERENT**, why it complains that error? Those situations occur at other folders, too. I can't just change their names separately to solve this problem.

Even I try `git add --ignore-errors .`, it doesn't works,too. It just stopped without ignoring this error. Anyone knows solutions?

Comment: What does `git config --get core.ignorecase` return?

Comment: I know your answer! Because I set `ignore case`, so git considers them as the same file, right?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: @naive231 What OS are you running? Windows and (with default settings) Mac file systems are case insensitive.

Comment: My OS is ubuntu, and this problem has been solved, thanks for caring.

Answer (score 75):

Edit .git/config to set ignorecase to false

```
[core]
  ignorecase = false
```

Can be set globally

```
$ git config --global core.ignorecase false
```

Comment: I ran your global fix, restarted the terminal and checked.  git config --get core.ignorecase  returns false now. But the problem persists.

Comment: Got it. I had to rename them to something nonsensical, commit, name correctly, commit, as per https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/51346/how-do-i-rename-a-file-in-git-that-differs-by-case-only

Comment: or similarly to update for a local repo via command line:
`$ git config --local core.ignorecase false`

Answer (score 17):

Use

```
git rm --cached <file>
```

This will completely remove the file's contents from the index but leaves it in the working directory. On commit, the files will be removed from the HEAD commit.

I would recommend to backup your project before doing that.

Comment: this one worked for me.

Answer (score 12):

Actually, I made such type of error by my ownself mistake.

> firstly, I created file name with  Small letters, later I changed file name in the capital letters **which is git not tracking**

1. Change the capitalization of the "file" name and add "1" to the end (or another symbol)
   Stage (without commit) = result "File1" - renaming files***
2. Remove "1" from the end
   Stage (without commit) = result "File" - renaming files (only capitalization now)
3. Now Do commit.

or try this

```
$ git config --local core.ignorecase false
```

[Reference](https://github.com/isaacs/github/issues/1520)

Comment: This command git config --local core.ignorecase false is what worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I had this same error in the Mac terminal.

For me it was fixed by using a different Git client.

For me, adding + committing via GitHub Desktop worked, without any changes to the git settings.