# Commit failed with error 0 files committed. Will not add file alias XXX already exists in index

Tags: android, git, android-studio, commit

I have refactored the name of messageServices to MessageServices, but I did it properly so not sure what's going on and why.

WHen I got to commit, I see that there are two checked files, messageServices and MessageServices, though in my file tree I only see the later.

I tried unchecking the first (lowercase m) but it still gives that error.
How do I solve this?

[image: This is the error I am getting when I try to commit]

Comment: The problem might be arising from the fact that you are working on Windows. Keep in mind that to Windows the two files are "the same", before and after renaming it.... and git depends on the FS to check the contents of the files and stuff. I've seen this kind of problem solved  so I'm not completely surprised by this. I've seen people recommending to use a temporary when renaming but I don't know the exact recipe.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Will not add file alias 'samefile' ('SameFile' already exists in index)" when \`git add\` operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25580440/will-not-add-file-alias-samefile-samefile-already-exists-in-index-when)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I made such type of error by my ownself mistake.

> Blockquote firstly, I created file name with  Small letters, later I changed file name in the capital letters **which is git not tracking**

1. **Change capitalization of "file" name and add "1" to the end (or another symbol)**
2. **Stage (without commit) = result "File1" - renaming files**
3. **Remove "1" from the end**
4. **Stage (without commit) = result "File" - renaming files (only capitalization now)**
5. **Now Do commit.**

> also try this- **$ git config --local core.ignorecase false**

[Reference](https://github.com/isaacs/github/issues/1520)